# Is valid return "Task<Task<MyObject>>" ? Or is better return "Task.FromResult(MyObject)"

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

My code is ok, but I'm wondering which style is better, how you will see, I'm playing with async methods.

Let me establish the context:

```
Parallel.ForEach(xmlAnimalList, async xml =>
        {
            taskList.Add(await Task.FromResult(ReadAnimalXML(xml, token)));
        });
```

this piece of code works pretty good with this method:

```
public async Task<Animal> ReadAnimalXML(string filename, CancellationToken token)
```

In the previous example you can see the **Task.FromResult()** right after await keyword. ReadAnimalXML method only returns a:

```
return new Animal();
```

**The second example is this:**

```
Parallel.ForEach(xmlAnimalList, async xml =>
        {
            taskList.Add(await ReadAnimalXML2(xml, token));
        });
```

this time the ReadAnimalXML2 method returns this:

```
public async Task<Task<Animal>> ReadAnimalXML2(string filename, CancellationToken token)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new Animal());
    }
```

**BUT!**

The second method ReadAnimalXML2 (which it seems really weird to me) returns a

```
Task<Task<Animal>>
```

*A task inside of a task.*

That's the reason why I return a *Task.FromResult(new Animal());*
**otherwise it won't work. Both ways are fine, but one is better.** Could you share your answer, and explain why?

I thank you that you have entered to see the question. **Coding is FUN!**

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Animal>> ReadXMLFromFolderAsync(string folderPath, CancellationToken token)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
        {
            return new List<Animal>();
        }

        List<Task<Animal>> taskList = new List<Task<Animal>>();

        List<string> xmlAnimalList = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.xml").ToList();

        Parallel.ForEach(xmlAnimalList, async xml =>
        {
            taskList.Add(await Task.FromResult(ReadAnimalXML(xml, token)));
        });

        return await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
    }

    public async Task<Animal> ReadAnimalXML(string filename, CancellationToken token)
    {
        XDocument document = XDocument.Load(filename);

        IEnumerable<XElement> ADN = await Task.Run(() => 
            document.Descendants("ADN").Where(adn => adn.Name.LocalName == "Dinosaur"), token);

        //populate the animal object

        return new Animal();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Animal>> ReadXMLFromFolderAsync2(string folderPath, CancellationToken token)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
        {
            return new List<Animal>();
        }

        List<Task<Animal>> taskList = new List<Task<Animal>>();

        List<string> xmlAnimalList = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.xml").ToList();

        Parallel.ForEach(xmlAnimalList, async xml =>
        {
            taskList.Add(await ReadAnimalXML2(xml, token));
        });

        return await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
    }

    public async Task<Task<Animal>> ReadAnimalXML2(string filename, CancellationToken token)
    {
        XDocument document = XDocument.Load(filename);

        IEnumerable<XElement> ADN = await Task.Run(() => document
            .Descendants("ADN")
            .Where(adn => adn
                .Name
                .LocalName == "Dinosaur")
                , token);

        //populate the animal object

        return Task.FromResult(new Animal());
    }
```

Comment: You should explain what you're trying achieve rather than which is better of things you don't understand.

Comment: If you wrote `ReadAnimalXML2()` you need to change it. imo, it should be `public Animal ReadAnimalXML2` and `return new Animal()` but if it has to be async, then `public Task<Animal> ReadAnimalXML2` and `return Task.FromResult(new Animal())`. If there is an `await` statement that's not being shown, then `public async Task<Animal> ReadAnimalXML2` and `return new Animal()` instead.

Comment: MMMM, both approaches are correct, but what of those methods are "more correct". In the real life code you guys use Task<Task<Object>> ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to achieve parallelism or asynchronity? Or both? I won't be surprised if you achieved neither of them, and the beef of your code is running synchronously on the UI thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're confusing parallelism with asynchrony, and doing neither one correctly.

If your method returns `Task.FromResult`, then it's not asynchronous. If you want to have asynchronous code, focus on the I/O - e.g., asynchronously do the I/O to load the file data from disk and then (synchronously) parse it as XML.

The `Parallel.ForEach` problems are more dangerous. First, you cannot use `async` methods with `Parallel.ForEach`; your code just happens to work because your `async` methods are not asynchronous. Also, you cannot use non-threadsafe methods like `List<T>.Add` from within parallel code. So pretty much all the code using `Parallel.ForEach` is wrong. But you probably don't need `Parallel.ForEach` anyway.

If you want to do asynchronous concurrency, then you just need LINQ's `Select` and `await Task.WhenAll`. If you want to set up a kind of pipeline that can do parallel processing, then you can either use TPL Dataflow, or use `Parallel.ForEach` **only** with synchronous code after the asynchronous parts are done.

Comment: Very nice answer Sir! I'll take that advice